# Считать символы с адреса

Tags: c++

Есть адрес , я 100% знаю что в нем хранится строка, нужно считать с адреса символы и затем проделать нужные мне операции.

Считываю мультибайтовую кодировку:

```
DWORD addr = 0x112233445566;

printf_s("%с\n", *((const char*)addr));
```

Отлично считался первый символ, пробуем считать первый символ с юникода:

```
wprintf_s(L"%с\n", *((const wchar_t*)addr));
```

Выдает какую-то билеберду, я знаю что в юникоде символ занимает 2 байта, но не пойму как нужно считать правильно.

Comment: а возможно там неверные данные. Пробовали просто распечатать в бинарном виде и посмотреть?

Comment: Начните проверку с вывода шестнадцетирички  printf("%#x\n", *((const char*)addr));  printf("%#x\n", *((const wchar_t*)addr));

Comment: @Yaroslav - выводит байты в обратном порядке, но эти байты соответствую символам

Comment: @KoVadim - да не верные вроде

Comment: @Abyx - там находится строка MZ, это начало exe приложения хедер короче или ты имеешь ввиду посмотреть что-то другое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Юникоды разные бывают, например, UTF-8, UTF-16LE и UTF-16BE (и их урезанные варианты UCS-2LE и UCS-2BE соответсвенно). MSVC, по умолчанию, работает с UCS-2LE.

А вообще было бы легче если бы вы привели то что вам выводится и то что вы там ожидаете.

Comment: ну вот например первые два символа MZ, а выводит какую-то каракулю

Comment: MZ? Вы пытаетесь распечатать PE хедер?

Comment: @KoVadim - нет, а хотя почему бы и нет, какие сложности у меня будут?

Comment: Сложностей не будет. Просто PE заголовок хоть и содержит строки, но вряд ли то, что Вы ожидаете.

Comment: @KoVadim - я просто хочу сделать поиск строки в модуле, с мультибайтовой кодировкой все получилось, а вот с юникодом проблема считать всего лишь один символ.

Comment: @KoVadim, вероятно что ваша проблема в том, что все ASCII-символы, в частности латинские буквы, в UTF-16 в качестве второго байта содержат 0. А еще, как нам говорит MSDN, спецификатор %с - это вывод одного символа. Для вывода строки существует %s

Comment: @ГерманБорисов у меня нет проблемы с аскии символами.